# secondary namenode failed to start ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.7 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: hadoop, ssh, namenode

**Starting secondary namenodes [7]**
**7: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.7 port 22: Connection timed out**

secondary namenode not started due to connection timeout
how to fix this on **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**?

**vivek@7:~$** start-all.sh

```sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as pradeep in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [7]
7: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.7 port 22: Connection timed out
2020-10-15 18:00:39,116 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

**vivek@7:~$** jps

```sh
6256 NodeManager
5649 NameNode
6098 ResourceManager
6586 Jps
5788 DataNode
```

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372985/secondary-namenode-failed-to-start-ssh-connect-to-host-0-0-0-7-port-22-connect) I fix this from there.

Comment: `0.0.0.7` is not a real IP address... Check your config files